# dynamic creation of CharFields in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I would like to take an input from the user(through CharField).Thereby it should use the CharField value to create that many number of CharFields(as entered) in the same page.

For e.g.
If user enters "3",after pressing OK it should create "3" Charfields under it.
Note : I would like to see the creation of 3 CharFields in the same page.

Comment: You need to write JavaScript code to do that. Can you post your Django forms and other snippets for review?

Answer (score 0):

The creation of multiple blank inputs is a function of django formsets. Capture the inputed number and pass it as the **extra** kwarg to the formset_factory.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

This means each CharField is a separate form and if you want any other inputs you'll have to mix forms and formsets which will make it more difficult to use built-in class-based form view functionality.